# Use all RAM memory in MS-DOS

Tags: memory, dos

How can I access more than Conventional and Extended memory?

Comment: MS-DOS is a footnote in information technology.

Comment: @0xA3, does that make the question any less legitimate? I'm sure there are problem spaces where MS-DOS is still a valid solution, even if you don't think it's optimal.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you not considering some form of Linux or embedded Linux? What you are asking for sounds like going deer hunting with a pea shooter.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: Sorry, please don't take my comments too seriously ;-) It is surely an interesting question and I would vote to reopen if this got closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XMS version 3.0 specification allows access to up to 4GB. See the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_memory#eXtended_Memory_Specification_.28XMS.29).

Comment: XMS is for storing data but not for running executable code in it. I need to use it to run code

Comment: becouse I have some diagnostic utilities that only run on dos

Comment: @user327104, if you need to run that much code you need to do some kind of code space swapping. I don't think there's anything that will do it automatically, you'll have to do it yourself and it's not a trivial process. I have to agree with Robert, you might be using the wrong technology here.

Answer (score 0):

MS-DOS is a 16-bit operating system, which limits its inherent ability to address large amounts of memory.  I believe the limit for addressable memory is 16 megabytes in protected mode, using *extended* memory (80286 processors and above).

See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_Limit

Nowadays, small application spaces, such as embedded controllers, typically use one of the many variants of Linux that are widely available.

Comment: I know that, so the question is about go over this limitation